# Split time by day of the week with an interval defined by two Zend_Date

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-date

I have two `Zend_Date` that represent an interval :

```
$start = new Zend_Date($punch->getStart());
$end = new Zend_Date($punch->getEnd());

$nbHours = $start->sub($end , Zend_Date::HOUR);
$nbMinutes = $start->sub($end , Zend_Date::MINUTE);

$hoursTotal = $nbHours->get(Zend_Date::HOUR);
$minutesTotal = $nbMinutes->get(Zend_Date::MINUTE);
```

Is there an simple way to split the interval by day of the week with `Zend_Date` when the interval > 24 hours?

For example, if I have an interval from Monday 8am to Tuesday 4:30pm, I would like to have an array containing `monday = 16h` and `tuesday = 16:30`.

Comment: So in your example you don want 34h30 you want like an array with `monday = 18h` and `tuesday = 16:30`?

Comment: @Krycke Thats exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Zend_Date for this, in fact it is probably better not to. You should use the [date/time classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) in PHP instead.

If I understand your question correctly you want an array of days and the hours worked for those days.

I first created a mock class to reflect your code example, I have assumed it is returning timestamps:-

```
class Punch
{
    public function getStart()
    {
        return time();
    }

    public function getEnd()
    {
        return strtotime('+36 hours 45 minutes');
    }
}
```

Then we set up the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) objects-

```
$Punch = new Punch();
$start = new DateTime();
$start->setTimestamp($Punch->getStart());
$end = new DateTime();
$end->setTimestamp($Punch->getEnd());
```

Then we use a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/dateinterval) object to generate our iterable [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/dateperiod):-

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1M');
$minutes = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
```

Then we simply iterate over it counting the minutes worked in each day:-

```
$format = 'l';
foreach($minutes as $minute){
    if(!isset($result[$minute->format($format)])) $result[$minute->format($format)] = 0;
    $result[$minute->format($format)]++;
}
```

See the [manual page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for acceptable formats.

We now have the number of minutes worked in each day, converting them to hours is trivial:-

```
foreach($result as $key => $r){
    $result[$key] = $r/60;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output (Obviously, you will get a different result running it at a different time) :-

```
array
  'Monday' => float 17.483333333333
  'Tuesday' => float 19.266666666667
```

So on Monday 17.48 hours were worked and 19.27 on Tuesday.

Alternatively:-

```
foreach($result as $key => $r){
    $result[$key] = floor($r/60) . ':' . $r % 60;
}
```

Would give the following output if that is closer to what you want:-

```
array
  'Monday' => string "17:29"
  'Tuesday' => string "19:16"
```

That's the simplest way I can think of doing it.